# Quotient of a reductive group by a non-smooth subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes, homogeneous-spaces, characteristic-p

This is a continuation of my question [Quotient of a  reductive group by a non-smooth central finite subgroup](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16261/).

Let $G$ be a smooth, connected, reductive $k$-group over a field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$.
Let $H\subset G$ be a $k$-subgroup, not necessarily smooth.
**Question 1:** Does the quotient $G/H$ exist as a $k$-variety?

I am interested in the following special case.
Let $H^{\rm mult}$ denote the largest quotient of $H$ which is a $k$-group ($k$-group scheme) of multiplicative type.
Set $H_1=\ker[H\to H^{\rm mult}]$.
I assume that $H_1$ is smooth, connected and semisimple. 
**Question 2:**  Does the quotient $G/H$ exist as a $k$-variety under this assumption? (I do not assume that $H^{\rm mult}$ is smooth.)

All comments and references are welcome!

Comment: For *any* group scheme $G$ of finite type over any field $k$ and *any* closed $k$-subgroup scheme $H$ of $G$, the fppf quotient sheaf $G/H$ is represented by a separated finite type $k$-scheme and the map $q:G \rightarrow G/H$ is faithfully flat (so $q$ inherits "any" property of $H \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(k)$ that is fppf-local on the base). In particular, if $G$ is smooth then $G/H$ is smooth. See SGA3, Exp. VI$_{\rm{A}}$, section 3 for the construction (doesn't use quasi-projective methods, but see footnote 35). For affineness when $G$ is affine and $H$ is normal, see VI$_{\rm{B}}$, 11.17.

Comment: "footnote 35" in the preceding comment refers to the new SMF edition.

Answer (score 3):

As xuhan points out, SGA3 provides a fairly comprehensive view of what can be said about quotients involving group schemes.   The price of this thoroughness is of course a lengthy technical treatment from which you might have trouble extracting just the amount of information you need.   (SGA3 is currently available online
[here](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~polo/SGA3/).)   In any case, it would be helpful if xuhan expands the comment here into a full answer.

Two later expositions may be worth consulting for your specific questions, since they are written in different styles:

Demazure-Gabriel, *Groupes algebraiques*, Chap. III, section 3.3.

Jantzen, *Representations of Algebraic Groups* (2nd ed., AMS, 2003), I.5 (especially the early sections of this chapter).   Note that Jantzen follows closely the Demazure-Gabriel treatment, but he tries to make his own version as self-contained as possible.   Moreover, his study of group schemes is slanted particularly toward work with reductive group schemes over fields of prime characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group scheme over a field, and let $N$ be an affine normal subgroup scheme. Then the quotient $Q=G/N$ certainly always exists as an affine algebraic group scheme, and it is smooth if $G$ is smoooth (the coordinate ring of $Q$ is contained in that of $G$, and hence geometrically reduced).